# Should app logout to logging screen or home screen?

Tags: android, navigation

I am building an app that requires the user to login to get access to their information. Within the app there are four branches all accessible via menu options. When the user logs in he is placed on the first screen of one of the branches.

I programmed the app so that when the user BACKs to the first screen of any branch, the activity stack is flushed and pressing back again exits the app.

The question: What is the best practice for exiting?

1. Should pressing back a second time log the user out and return to the login screen.
2. Or should pressing back log the user out and return the user to the android home screen?

I have seen both ways of doing it and not sure what criteria I should look at to make the proper usability decision.

To clarify the flow:

[Android Home Screen] -> [App Login Screen] -> [Internal App Branch]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually capture the Back button, give the user a Toast notification like "Press Back button again to exit".  I capture the System.currentTimeMillis and compare subsequent presses for a threshold of 2 seconds or something close to that.  I've seen a couple apps do that and it seems pretty intuitive to me.

Comment: I have seen that as well and like it and is what I have implemented.  But what I was referring to was after pressing the BACK key a second time should I return to the app's login screen or return to the Android Home Screen. The example you mentioned that I have seen as well returns to the Android Home Screen and skips the login screen.

Comment: yeah...when the user exits the app, they want to exit. I think it would be annoying for most cases to have to click a third time to get back to the previous application or home screen.

Comment: Unless you have a really good reason, don't require a user to press back twice. What is this supposed to accomplish?

Comment: Do you expect users to log out of the app a lot? Most apps I've seen have an explicit log out function, hitting back never logs you out or takes you to a log in screen.

Comment: @Mike...users actually requested this feature for my app (might be a slightly different use case than OP because my app is not login-enabled).  Sometimes they expect the back button to hide a dialog or back out to a different view, or sometimes they just hit Back button by accident and hate to have it hide the app right away.

Comment: The apps that I have seen with a logout option are usually the ones that have a background service running such Google Navigator and Skype. But my app requires the user to login, I need to prevent an accidental logout of the app by BACKing into the login screen.

Answer (score 0):

If the home screen does not require authentication then I would prefer this method. This is a highly subjective question, though. I'm sure there are other people who would disagree with me and say they prefer the log in screen. That's why it's pretty subjective :)

Comment: By home screen I was referring to the Android Home screen and not the app's.